# Any way to initialise objects with "initialise" instead of "initialize"?

Tags: ruby

So, because I am British, I always initialise objects with the name `initialise()` and quite often get the error `Error in initialize: (wrong number of arguments (given n, expected 0))`.

Is there some meta programming I can do to make `initialize()` for all objects try to call `initialise()`?

Comment: I agree with you on the spelling preference, but it might not be a good idea to write your code with this deviation from what people expect. At least the language it's written in is pretty close to your first language: some people don't even have that advantage.

Comment: @Sancarn : You open a box of worms here. What if both `initialize` and `initialise` are defined in a class? Which one has "preference"? Also, you might use a library or gem where someone legally defines a `self.initialise`, which however is not intended to be used as constructor, and at the same time has not defined a `initialize` method, because he is happy with the default. I certainly would not want to debug errors resulting from this kind of problem....

Comment: Yes @user1934428 you are quite correct, that is a potential issue. That being said, it's also going to be such a rare occurrence that I'm willing to accept it as a weakness. Could also throw a "WARN" to STDOUT, which would allow you to easily identify where it fails.

Comment: It is interesting that this a concern for you such that you are treating this as a written paper in your native tongue. What if matz had written ruby in Japanese (his native tongue) and you had to type "初期化する"  would you still have the same concern? method definitions are symbolic and only have the meaning that the underlying code defines.

Comment: @engineersmnky If matx had written Ruby in Japanese, I would not be using Ruby at all, as is the case for many people. Do you use the language Aheui?... The fact of the matter is, its very annoying when you get loads of errors constantly due to Americanizations... I get your point, but would you use Ruby if the method was named `asd98fi12jk2naoshujibdh1sdasd2asdfa2rfxs`? There's a reason why people don't use lolcode language for serious projects... It's annoying, as is `initialize`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this might work; but anyone reading or using your code might hate you. :P

```
class BasicObject
  alias american_initialize initialize
  private def initialize(*args, &block)
    if respond_to?(:initialise)
      initialise(*args, &block)
    else
      american_initialize(*args, &block)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Works like a charm :) I'll add a warning message in there just in case it is "accidentally" called at the wrong time :P

Answer (score 2):

Please don't do this. Ever. But let's teach people how to shoot themselves on the foot:

```
class BasicObject
  def self.new(*args)
    if instance_methods.member? :initialise
      allocate.initialise(*args)
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

So what's happening here: We just overwrote the `.new` definition. By default it calls `#allocate` and then `#initialize` passing down the `*args` you sent to it.

`.allocate` allocates the memory for the object but does not call `#initialize` over it, so we check if the object has a `#initialise` instance method defined, if it has it gets called, otherwise default behaviour (`super`) is used.

Comment: What is the `super` of `BasicObject.new`?

Comment: @sawa that should be `Class#new` in this case (and I think it would be cleaner / less confusing to just override `Class#new` instead).

Comment: @sawa Yep. `super` will be called on the context of the invoker and will travel up the inheritance chain until it finds `.new` defined somewhere (usually `Class`). @Stefan I'm not sure if overriding this in `Class` would work, or if any changes would need to be made as `Class.new` is kinda of a special beast.

Answer (score 0):

The [`did_you_mean`](https://github.com/yuki24/did_you_mean) gem (comes with Ruby 2.3 and later) can help you to avoid such errors:

```
require 'did_you_mean/experimental'

class Foo
  def initialise
  end
end
```

Output:

```
warning: initialise might be misspelled, perhaps you meant initialize?
```

The [code](https://github.com/yuki24/did_you_mean/blob/master/lib/did_you_mean/experimental/initializer_name_correction.rb) behind this feature uses [`method_added`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Module.html#method-i-method_added) to monitor the addition of new methods and prints a warning if the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between the method's name and *"initialize"* is ≤ 2.

Comment: Weird that you have to require the module... Thanks for the work around, although it isn't what I was after, for some this may be ideal. Unfortunately for me it won't really work though given that I am in 1.9.3 and cannot upgrade.